# Request for member 'hosted graph' in something not a structure or union

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I'm making a Core Plot app.

What I have done so far:

1. Opened my projects XIB in Interface Builder
2. Dragged another `UIView` onto my `viewController` and changed it to a `CPTGraphHostingView` so I can have it as a Core Plot Graph. (The reason I have put in another UIVIew and renamed it to `CPTGraphHostingView` is because I want to Core Plot view to be a small area of the screen rather then it be full screen, so then it gives me room to add UILabels below it and other things.
3. Then in Interface Builder I clicked the Core Plot view and then I clicked **File > Write Class Files** (So I can execute code to the Core Plot view)
4. Then I copied the code from the Core Plot iPhone example (I copied the code from the class with bar chart code).

So now, in the Core Plot class in my project I have the bar chart code in it from the Core Plot Example project.

But I have one little issue.
When I go to compile the code it says this:

[image]

Just to let you know, the only reason I am copying the code from Core Plots example is because I want to make sure everything works properly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you made your own `CPTGraphHostingView` class instead of using the one provided by Core Plot. The problem was step 3 in your question. You need to set the class for the new `UIView`, but don't write the class files. The Core Plot setup code normally goes into your view controller.